# When triggering a jquery event, Is there any way to change the event object?

Tags: jquery

Html:

```
<ul class="productList">
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>C</li>
   <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.productList').click(function(e){
    var li = $(e.target);
    //bla bla bla
});
```

The problem is, from some other place, i want trigger the above event and when triggering i want to pass the a specific `li` as `event target` to that function.  Simply, i want to modify the `event` object and set some `li` as target in that object. Is there any way to do it in jquery?

I'm aware of binding the `click` directly to the `li` in which case i will be able to avoid this problem. But its a huge list, it makes the app very slow.

Any suggestions would be appreciative!!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the `li` element to `jQuery` and trigger the event:

```
$(referenceToLi).click();
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great. But not in IE 8. Can you guess what could be the reason.

Comment: @TamilVendhan: That should work in IE too. Are you absolutely sure?

Comment: I'm sorry. I think its caching issue. It works like charm in IE too :)